# WSO2 identity server api

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am designing a new application that needs identity management functionality (i.e. managing user accounts and roles).  I would like to delegate that functionality to an Identity Server.

1. Is there a REST or SOAP API's exposed by WSO2 Identity Server for managing user accounts  (e.g. similar to [OpenAM's REST api](https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/Use+OpenAM+RESTful+Services#UseOpenAMRESTfulServices-IdentityManagement))?

I did find the WSO2 AuthenticationAdmin wsdl `https://localhost:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin?wsdl` but that doesn't have user account management functionality.

2. Is there an authorative list of all the wsdl's that are exposed by the WSO2 platform? So far, I've found the AuthenticationAdmin wsdl and EventBrokerService wsdl by searching on google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) You can try using the UserAdmin located at `https://localhost:9443/services/UserAdmin?wsdl` as well.

2) You can do this by using the osgi console. Start the server using -DosgiConsole flag, i.e. ./wso2server.sh -DosgiConsole or ./wso2server.bat -DosgiConosle

then after the server start you will get the osgi console. Enter listAdminServices and you will get the list. ex:

```
osgi> listAdminServices
Admin services deployed on this server:
1. ProvisioningAdminService, ProvisioningAdminService, https://10.150.3.140:9443/services/ProvisioningAdminService/
```

All the commands such as 'listAdminServices' are listed by typing 'help' from the osgi console.

Note: All servers expose Web Service APIs which can be used for to gain access to back end functionality.

Comment: There is some good information about the wso2 api here: http://blog.facilelogin.com/2008/10/wsas-hiddedn-services.html