# How do I get the list of SOAP services exposed by WSO2 Identity Server?

Tags: service, wso2, identity

I've recently started looking at WSO2 Identity Server as an alternative to what my company is currently using.

I'm finding it difficult to determine what SOAP and REST services are exposed and what the URLs for those are.

I've tried starting the server (on my Windows machine) with wso2server.bat -DosgiConosle , but I can't seem to get the OSGi console after the server has started.

Is there any other way to get the list of services exposed by the product?

Also, I'm not aware of the service API being documented and made available - Are there plans to do this?

Any help in getting the list of services or an instruction on how to do it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

WSO2 products currently do not have a documented service API. However you can use OSGi console to view the available service components details.

Make sure that when you start WSO2 IS with osgi console the following log is visible, which says that the console is enabled.

```
sh wso2server.sh -DosgiConsole
```

JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /jdk1.6.0_30
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /wso2is-4.1.0

**OSGi console has been enabled with options: -console**

After server is properly started, press enter and osgi> console will be displayed.

```
[2013-07-24 16:33:57,215]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  WSO2 Carbon started in 17 sec
[2013-07-24 16:33:57,437]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Mgt Console URL  : https://localhost:9443/carbon/

osgi>
```

By entering necessary osgi commands you can see the activated OSGI service etc. For example if you need to see available services use,

osgi> services

This will list down all the services in the runtime. Use appropriate filters to find the WSO2 IS services by referring this [blog post](http://pradeepfernando.blogspot.com/2011/10/debugging-your-osgi-application-using.html).

osgi> ls

This shows all the osgi service components along with their component ID and life-cycle status. If you need to now on particular service component use ls -c  command.

The following question thread has useful information on WSO2 IS API too.

[WSO2 identity server api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696775/wso2-identity-server-api)

Answer (score 2):

start the server with the following command(case sensitive)

```
wso2server.bat -DosgiConsole
```

and you should see the  `osgi>` console

Answer (score 0):

This link leads to an information how to list admin services exposed on WSO2 product (osgi console must be enabled)

[List all ws in wso2](http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.cz/2013/02/list-all-web-services-in-wso2.html)

Answer (score 0):

1) Start the server with osgi console.

```
wso2server.bat -DosgiConsole
```

2) Run following command 'listAdminServices'

```
osgi> listAdminServices
```

This should show all the admin services exposed by the server.