# Have Governance Registry discover Endpoints and APIs from ESB

Tags: registry, wso2, wso2-esb

I have successfully configured an ESB instance so that it's services are being discovered by a Governance Registry instance following [this guide](https://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance450/WS-Discovery+with+Governance+Registry). However, I wish to know whether it's possible that endpoints and APIs from an ESB be also discovered and published by the Governance Registry.

Answer (score 0):

From the guide you linked it seems that one you are using an admin service from GREG

```
https://localhost:9443/services/DiscoveryProxy
```

for the discovery. I haven't tried it but to me it looks like it'll be possible to do the same for ESB.

As a side note you can view the carbon admin services like described here: [How do I get the list of SOAP services exposed by WSO2 Identity Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830659/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-soap-services-exposed-by-wso2-identity-server)

The alternative is to setup a shared registry by setting up a shared database. This way once you create an endpoint in the WSO2 ESB it'll be saved in the shared registry of the two servers and therefore it'll be available in GREG's registry as well. This way you can connect multiple servers to one registry.

This approach is documented here: https://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS321/Config+and+Governance+Partitions+in+a+Remote+Registry