# WSO2 Identity Server REST and SOAP call

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

WSO2 Identity Server : I am new to WSO2 Identity Server. Could somebody help to get list of REST call and soap call supported by WSO2 Identity Server

Answer (score 2):

[This blog post](http://blog.facilelogin.com/2010/05/managing-users-and-roles-with-wso2.html) has an example of using WSO2-IS APIs.

Take a look at the answer to the following question also. [WSO2 identity server api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696775/wso2-identity-server-api)

Comment: Those are the SOAP APIs. These are the REST APIs,
https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users, https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Groups,
https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo,
https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token,
https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 products are manage internally SOAP web services known as admin services. The admin service wsdl as bellow.

https://localhost:9443/services/UserAdmin?wsdl

Note: you cannot view the wsdl of admin service by default due to security reason.  Configure the following steps to enable and invoke the admin service wsdl.

1. Set the `<HideAdminServiceWSDLs>` element to false in `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/carbon.xml` file.

   ```
   <HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDL>
   ```
2. Restart the server.

Also you can use OSGi console to get the list of SOAP Services exposed in Identity Server and view the available service components details. To enable osgi console doing following steps.

1. Get osgi console by executing the following command.

   ```
   <IS_Home>/bin/wso2server.bat –DosgiConsole
   ```

   After successfully started the server press ‘Enter’ key and osgi>console will be displayed.
2. To get all admin services that are deployed on this server.

   ```
   osgi> listAdminServices
   ```
3. List down all hidden services that are deployed on this server.

   ```
   osgi>listHiddenServices
   ```

All services expose Web Service APIs which can be used for to gain access to back end functionality.